# Add function in cakephp suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP, so I may be missing something obvious.

I have an add form that was working and saving to the database, and suddenly stopped. I didn't think I added anything significant, mostly just styling stuff...unfortunately my last backup was before I had finished the add function, so I don't have a way to go back to when it worked. If anyone can take a look and see where I'm going wrong, I would appreciate it!

My Task model:

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class Task extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = 'User';

public $validate = array(
    'task_name' => array(
        'custom' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'This field accepts letters and numbers only.'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
            'message' => 'Task name cannot exceed 50 characters'
        )
    ),
    'frequency' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    ),
    'day' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    ),
    'user_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric'
        )
    ),
    'month_type' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => false
        )
    ),
    'month_number' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => false
        )
    ),
    'month_day' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    ),
    'day_number' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => false
        )
    )
);
}
```

The add function from my TasksController file:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {   
        $this->Task->create();
        if ($this->Task->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Task saved!'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved'));
        }   
    }
}
```

And the form from my tasks/add.ctp file:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Task',array('class' => 'taskForm'));
$userId = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');?>

<fieldset>
    <legend class="welcomeText"><?php echo __('Add a Task'); ?></legend>
    <?php 

        echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', array('value' => $userId));

        echo $this->Form->input('task_name', array('label' => 'Task Name', 'maxLength' => 50));

        //set frequency
        echo "<p>How often should this task be done?</p>";
        $options = array('unset' => 'Decide Later','daily' => 'Daily','weekly' => 'Weekly','monthly' => 'Monthly');
        $attributes = array('value' => 'unset','separator' => '<br/>','class' => 'frequencyRadio','legend' => false);
        echo $this->Form->radio('frequency', $options, $attributes);

        //optional answers

        //if "weekly" is selected
        echo "<div id=\"weeklyRadio\" >";
        echo "<p>Set a day of the week for this task?</p>";
        $options = array('unset' => 'Decide later','monday' => 'Monday','tuesday' => 'Tuesday','wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
        'thursday' => 'Thursday','friday' => 'Friday','saturday' => 'Saturday','sunday' => 'Sunday');
        $attributes = array('value' => 'unset','separator' => '<br/>','class' => 'weeklyRadio','legend' => false);
        echo $this->Form->radio('day',$options,$attributes);
        echo "</div>"; 

        //if "monthly" is selected
        ?>
        <div id="monthlyRadio">
            <p>Schedule this task?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="data[Task][month_type]" id="TaskMonthTypeUnset" 
                value="unset" class="monthlyRadio" required="required" checked="checked" />
            <label for="TaskMonthTypeUnset">Decide later</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="data[Task][month_type]" id="TaskMonthTypeNumber" 
                value="number" class="monthlyRadio" required="required" />
            <label for="TaskMonthTypeNumber">
                <?php

                    echo "On the ";
                    $options = array(1 => '1st',2 => '2nd',3 => '3rd',4 => '4th',5 => '5th',6 => '6th',7 => '7th',8 => '8th',9 => '9th',
                            10 => '10th',11 => '11th',12 => '12th',13 => '13th',14 => '14th',15 => '15th', 16 => '16th',
                            17 => '17th',18 => '18th',19 => '19th',20 => '20th',21 => '21st',22 => '22nd',23 => '23rd',
                            24 => '24th',25 => '25th',26 => '26th',27 => '27th',28 => '28th',29 => '29th',30 => '30th',31 => '31st');                       
                    echo $this->Form->select('month_number',$options,array('value' => null));
                    echo " of the month";
                ?>
            </label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="data[Task][month_type]" id="TaskMonthTypeDay" value="day" class="monthlyRadio" required="required" />
            <label for="TaskMonthTypeDay">
                <?php

                    echo "On the ";
                    $options = array(1 => '1st',2 => '2nd',3 => '3rd',4 => '4th',5 => '5th',6 => 'last');
                    echo $this->Form->select('day_number',$options,array('value' => null));
                    echo "&nbsp";
                    $options = array('monday' => 'Monday','tuesday' => 'Tuesday','wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
                            'thursday' => 'Thursday','friday' => 'Friday','saturday' => 'Saturday','sunday' => 'Sunday');
                    echo $this->Form->select('month_day',$options,array('value' => null));
                    echo " of the month";
                ?>
            </label>
        </div>




    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->submit('Add Task', array('class' => 'formSubmit',  'title' => 'Create Task') ); 
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

There is also a javascript file that shows and hides the optional radio buttons, but I assume that wouldn't have anything to do with why it stopped saving to the database.

When I click the "Add Task" button on the form, it doesn't do anything at all (doesn't save to the database, and doesn't redirect to the index.ctp view like it used to). No idea what I'm missing here!

### UPDATE

Fixed the problem! The places in my form where I specified a default value of null, it was passing an empty string. The data model was expecting numeric values for 'month_number' and 'day_number,' so it wasn't processing.

I fixed it by adding 0 => '' to the selection list, and specifying 0 as the default value, and now it works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see errors in your code.
Add this in the controller add and make a debug for more information about what happens.

```
public function add() {
    $this->loadModel('Task');
    debug($this->request->is('post')); //try this first
    //debug($this->request); //after try this
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {   
        $this->Task->create();
        if ($this->Task->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Task saved!'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved'));
        }   
    }
```

}

loadModel adds this. update your question with that display the debug, and I update mi answer.

Comment: Thanks. I ran it with the debug code and it's giving me a value of 'true.'

Comment: now in  debug($this->request->data); just for see if not there a error in a value

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was that when I was specifying a default value of null, it was passing an empty string. The model was expecting numeric values for a couple of those, so it wasn't processing.

Comment: well, if you please fix your problem, based on the procedures of debug that I said,put resolved. serves me that I can not ask until I answer 7 questions. if not leave it like that. >).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the submit form button assigned to a different class, which is why its not firing the form.

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Add Task', array('class' => 'formSubmit',  'title' => 'Create Task') );
```

Try changing it to either of the following

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Add Task', array(
'class' => 'taskForm',  
'title' => 'Create Task')); 

echo $this->Form->button('Add Task', array(
'class' => 'taskForm',  
'title' => 'Create Task',
'action' => 'submit;));
```

or amend the form ending tag to see if it fires properly.

Change this

```
echo $this->Form->end();
```

to

```
echo $this-Form->end('Submit');
```

Comment: I tried both those suggestions and I'm unfortunately still having the same issue. The formSubmit class was so I could style the button, but I took it out in case it was causing problems.